# Multiple occurrences in String

Tags: java, regex, gwt

I searched a bit about that and tried load of stuff but can figure it out.

In a simple String like `"a=:a OR b=:b OR c=:c"` I would like to retrieve : `:a` `:b` `:c`

Here is what I tried using GWT RegExp :

```
RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile("(:\\w+)", "g"); // Tried without 'g'
MatchResult matcher = regExp.exec("a=:a OR b=:b OR c=:c");
```

But this returns 2 groups ":a",":a" ... I tried stuffs on an online tester but couldn't get what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First as said Adam Matan, I should have escaped the `:`.
But I wasn't using the classes as it should be.
`regExp.exec` should be executed multiple time in a while loop to get all possible values.

Something like :

```
    MatchResult matcher = regExp.exec(this.sqlFilter, "g");
    while (matcher != null) {
        ...

        matcher = regExp.exec(this.sqlFilter);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape the `:`:

```
"(\\:\\w+)"
```

[Direct link](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDgsSBlJlY2lwZRjKzCUM/index.html) to online tester with your example.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I agree it works on the website but not with Google classes. Only return `:a` using global or not

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped for the `:` but in fact I wasn't using the class the way it should be

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var str="a=:a OR b=:b OR c=:c";
var patt1=/:[\w+]/g;
var arr = str.match(patt1);
```

Comment: No, the question is aiming at Java.